# Why does printf("%d\n", printf("%d\b", a)) work this way?

Tags: c, escaping, printf

This is my C code, compiled with gcc.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{ 
    int a=1; 
    switch(a)
    {
       int x=10;
       case 1:
           printf("%d\n",printf("%d\b",x));
           break;
       default:
           printf("%d\n",printf("%d\b",x));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

printf() is supposed to return the number of elements it printed successfully.
`printf("%d\b", x)` should have printed 10 by itself(since the \b takes the printing pointer one step behind (to the digit 0 in 10) and there is nothing to print after that.
So it should have just printed 10. That is 2 characters. Now the outer printf would display 2.
The output should have been 102.
The output I actually see is 2.

And in case of nested `printf`s is the printing pointer position remembered? I mean, if there is a `\b` in the inside `printf` , it would take the printing pointer one step behind. And when the control now goes to the outer `printf`, is that changed position remembered? Will it overwrite over that last character?

Comment: I'm sorry, the original program is the one I've shown in the edit. I thought removing the switch wouldn't make a difference(as you might see from my 1st edit).

Comment: And, I don't think the ideone result is right. I just checked the very same code with GCC. It gives me `13`

Comment: @ShawnChin: Note that the output shown by ideone.com likely doesn't match what you'd see running the program in a terminal. ideone.com appears to ignore backspace characters.

Comment: @KeithThompson sorry, my intention was to point out that the code does not match the OP's expectations. I should have been more explicit that I expected the results to be either "103" or "13" depending on whether `\b` takes effect.

Comment: Removing the `switch` made a *huge* difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
printf("%d\b",x)
```

prints the characters `'1'`, `'0'` (because x==10) and `\b`. The `\b` is a backspace character; if you print to a terminal, it will print `10` and then move the cursor back one column.

A call to `printf` returns the number of characters it printed; in this case, the result is 3 (yes, `'\b'` counts as a character).

```
printf("%d\n",printf("%d\b",x));
```

The inner `printf` call works as I explained above, and returns 3. The outer `printf` call prints `"3\n"`.

So the entire statement will print:

```
10\b3\n
```

The `'\b'` causes the `3` to be replace the `0` on the screen, so the final displayed result (when I run the program on my system) is:

```
13
```

If I pipe the output through `cat -v`, I get:

```
10^H3
```

where `^H` represents the backspace character.

**EDIT :**

The question was just edited, and the modified program's behavior is quite different.  The switch statement causes control to jump *past* the declaration `int x = 10;`, but into the scope in which `x` is declared. As a result, `x` is uninitialized when `printf` is called. This causes undefined behavior, and most likely garbage output (I just got `-1217572876^H12`). If `x` happens to be `0`, I suppose you'd get `0^H2`, which would look like `2`.

Whatever you're trying to do, please find a better way to do it.

Comment: Any idea why the result from the uncommented portion in my question displays 2 ?

Comment: Is there a term for that behavior where x gets declared but not defined? I'm trying to find out if there are other such similar situations of "statement jumping".

Comment: @learner: As C defines the terms, `x` is both declared and defined; it's not *initialized*. It can happen without "statement jumping", for example `int x;` (at block scope) leaves `x` uninitialized.

Comment: please help me to more about these things "%d\n" what are these called? in what logic  those mean 0/1?

Comment: @Neail You're asking how `printf` works. Find a good C book or tutorial. I can't explain it meaningfully in comments.

Comment: anyone having the same question as mine please visit this link- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: @Neail I'm sure that's useful information for some, but the question was about C, not Java.

Comment: @KeithThompson it seems the logic I am looking for is same, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Neail If you have a question, post a question. It's not going to be useful to discuss this in comments.